# Writing stderr from one process to another process c++/unix

Tags: c++, unix, communication, distributed-computing

I have one application where parent process launches jobs over distributed farm system like lsf/vnc .
Now what I want is whenever there is any error reported in thier respective log by any of the jobs launch , error should be redirected to main stdout screen of parent process. so that there is no need to monitor log of each job separately. 
I have never used pipe/semaphores in my codes but I can learn that if needed.

Please suggest some efficient solution. I am working on Linux/Solaris platform.

Thanks

Comment: so you want something like 'grep ERROR logs/allLogs.* > ttyConsole` (this will NOT work, it is just pseudocode). It might help to spend a little time editing your question to illustrate your use-case. For me, it is hard to make your description and title relate to the same problem (and why mention C++ in your title, do you need/expect to modify C++ code to achieve your requirement?) Good luck.

Comment: How are you starting LSF jobs? Are you calling `lsrun` with something like `system("lsrun ...");`, are you using the LSF C API (i.e. `ls_execv()`) or some other mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you launch the subprocesses there are different mechanics how to set their standard handles.

In general, you'll have to set their stderr handle to be the same your stdout handle.

Keep in mind that this has nothing to do with the "logs" that you mention; it's about what your subject says (redirecting stderr).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the stderr of the children to be the same as the stdout of the parent, then you may be able to simply launch the parent with its stderr tied to its stdout.  If `cmd` is the command to launch the parent, try:

```
$ cmd 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use dup2() library call in order to duplicate STDERR in the child process to desired file descriptor, for example to STDOUT of any other descriptor, which can be opened before by the parent process and inherited by the child process after fork().
Try to read manula page for "dup2" call.